# how to make rgba in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

Hi guys i'm new with Stylus, want to know how to make a ***rgba*** color

in **Less** you can use *fade(@color, 10%)* how i can make this with **[Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)**?

Less

```
 background-color: fade(#ccc, 10%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `rgba()`:

```
 background-color: rgba(#ccc, 10%);
```